# rstudio-server error: ERROR system error 28 (No space left on device)

Tags: r, rstudio-server

My disk ran out of space a while ago and the rstudio-server running on my machine gave me an error about that. I have cleaned up space but the error keep showing up:

```
05 Jan 2015 16:14:19 [rsession-user] ERROR system error 28 (No space left on device)                   
[path=/home/user/rstudio-project]; OCCURRED AT: core::Error 
core::system::file_monitor::<unnamed>::addWatch(const core::FileInfo&, const 
core::FilePath&, bool, int, core::system::file_monitor::<unnamed>::Watches*) 
/home/ubuntu/rstudio/src/cpp/core/system/file_monitor/LinuxFileMonitor.cpp:225; LOGGED 
FROM: core::Error session::modules::files::FilesListingMonitor::start(const 
core::FilePath&, core::json::Array*)   
/home/ubuntu/rstudio/src/cpp/session/modules/SessionFilesListingMonitor.cpp:66
```

The error shows up on the console every time I click a folder on the file pane. I have tried to restart the server but not helpful. I just tried to update to the most recent rstudio-server (0.98.1091), but it still happens. Any help is appreciated!

I am running ubuntu 14.04 64bit, by the way.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Did any of you find a solution to this? It is quite annoying..

Comment: I didn't find any solution. I have not used Rstudio for a long time, partially because of this.

Comment: You need to get onto the remote machine by other means (`ssh` is one way) and delete sufficient files to make room.  There is no magic shortcut.

Comment: You will have to inspect the contents of the remote file system. If you don't have shell access you can try `system('du -h')`, etc. Check `/tmp` dir sometimes shiny and rstudio-server can leave behind copious artefacts that can be safely purged to free up space.

Comment: @qkhhly Can you please add to the question the output of `df -h` and `df -i`?

Comment: @YogevNeumann oh that was 8 years ago... no way i can give you the output of `df -h` or `df -i` now.